# obtener los datos de un usuario introduciendo su id

Tags: c#

Hola necesito obtener el nombre de un registro, al introducir su id en una caja de texto.
He hecho el código pero es erróneo porque solo me imprime el nombre que se encuentra en la primera fila. ósea si el id que he introducido es el del ultimo usuario , el nombre que obtengo es el nombre que se encuentra en la primera fila y yo necesito obtener el nombre del id os dejo mi código para que me podáis decir donde he fallado. programo con c#

```
  private void OptenerNombreGA()
    {
        
        RNPersona persona = new RNPersona(); // instanciamos la capa RNPersona para la consulta de la tabla del personalGA
        
        RNAssistance rNassistance = new RNAssistance();
        EnAssistance enAssistance = new EnAssistance();

        DataTable data = new DataTable(); 
        data = persona.BD_LeerPersonnaNomPrenomGA(); //Consultamos la tabla persona para traer los nombre 


        try
        {

           
            string EstadoEntrada = "Ponctuelle";
            string EstadoSalida = "Retard";
            string Assistance = "Present";



            enAssistance.id = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["id"]);
            enAssistance.nombre = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["nomprenom"]);
       
            rNassistance.RN_ResgitroAssistanceGA(enAssistance);

            if (BDAssistance.Saved == true)
            {
                if (data.Rows.Count == 0) return;

                label_NombreRegistado.Visible = true;
                label_Identification.Visible = true;
                label_AvisoRegistro.Visible = true;
                label_NombreRegistado.Text = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["nomprenom"]);
                label_Identification.Text = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["id"]);
                label_AvisoRegistro.Text = " Enregistrement correct";
                //pictureBox_PhotoPerfil = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["photoperfil"]);

                pictureBox_RegistroBueno.Visible = true;
                label_AvisoRegistro.Text = "Registro de asistencia correcto";

            }
            else
            {
                Form_Filtro filtro = new Form_Filtro();
                Form_ProcedOK procederror = new Form_ProcedOK();
                procederror.label_RegistroCorrecto.Text = "Une erreur s'est produite.";
                procederror.label_RegistroCorrecto.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                procederror.pictureBox_ProcedErreur.Visible = true;
                procederror.BringToFront();
                filtro.Show();
                procederror.ShowDialog();
                filtro.Hide();

                this.Tag = "A";
                this.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        


    }
```

esta es la funcion que busca el id:

ALTER proc [dbo].[Sp_ConsultanomPreTableA]
@id nvarchar(50)
as
select id,nomprenom, adresse from Table_GA where id = @id

Comment: Dónde estas pasando el id para obtener el nombre?

Comment: no le he pasado el id solo lo introduzco en el textbox

Comment: Y la función que busca el nombre por id? La podrías incluir? O tampoco la has construido?

Comment: la acabo de incluir

Comment: Un alter para obtener un registro que es un select, es algo muy raro.. si no le pasas el id, como sabe que registro devolverte? falta toda esa informacion...

Comment: si si al final le he pasado el id y ha resultado lo que queria, gracias Dios os bendiga a todos vosotros

Answer (score 0):

Respondo a mi pregunta:

he cambiado mi consulta de:

ALTER proc [dbo].[Sp_ConsultanomPreTableA]
as
select *from table_GA

A:

ALTER proc [dbo].[Sp_ConsultanomPreTableA]
@id nvarchar(50)
as
select id,nomprenom from Table_GA where id = @id

y en mi codigo le envio el id que escribo en la caja de texto

private void ObtenerNombreGA()
{

```
        RNPersona persona = new RNPersona(); // instanciamos la capa RNPersona para la consulta de la tabla del personalGA
        
        RNAssistance rNassistance = new RNAssistance();
        EnAssistance enAssistance = new EnAssistance();

        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        string id = bunifuCustomTextbox1.Text.Trim(); 
        data = persona.BD_LeerPersonnaNomPrenomGA(id); //Consultamos la tabla persona para traer los nombre 


        try
        {

           
            string EstadoEntrada = "Ponctuelle";
            string EstadoSalida = "Retard";
            string Assistance = "Present";

            enAssistance.idEmploye = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["id"]);
            enAssistance.nomPrenomEmploye = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["nomprenom"]);
            enAssistance.heureEntree = DateTime.Now;
            enAssistance.etatEntree = EstadoEntrada;
            enAssistance.heureSortie = DateTime.Now;
            enAssistance.etatSortir = EstadoSalida;
            enAssistance.assistance = Assistance;

            rNassistance.RN_ResgitroAssistanceGA(enAssistance);

            if (BDAssistance.Saved == true)
            {
                if (data.Rows.Count == 0) return;

                label_NombreRegistado.Visible = true;
                label_Identification.Visible = true;
                label_AvisoRegistro.Visible = true;
                label_NombreRegistado.Text = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["nomprenom"]);
                label_Identification.Text = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["id"]);
                label_AvisoRegistro.Text = " Enregistrement correct";
                //pictureBox_PhotoPerfil = Convert.ToString(data.Rows[0]["photoperfil"]);

                pictureBox_RegistroBueno.Visible = true;
                label_AvisoRegistro.Text = "Registro de asistencia correcto";

            }
            else
            {
                Form_Filtro filtro = new Form_Filtro();
                Form_ProcedOK procederror = new Form_ProcedOK();
                procederror.label_RegistroCorrecto.Text = "Une erreur s'est produite.";
                procederror.label_RegistroCorrecto.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                procederror.pictureBox_ProcedErreur.Visible = true;
                procederror.BringToFront();
                filtro.Show();
                procederror.ShowDialog();
                filtro.Hide();

                this.Tag = "A";
                this.Close();

            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

        


    }
```

ahora me pone los datos del id introducido